# Function to return a cursor(result set)

Tags: sql-server-2005, function, cursor, return-value

Is it possible to return a cursor from a user defined function in MS SQL Server2005? If it is, how is that done?

Comment: won't you get enough with UDF that returns TABLE?

Comment: if you really need some encapsulated code to return a cursor, you can have a stored procedure that creates a global cursor... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189238(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the result returned, [user-defined functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189593.aspx) in SQL Server [can be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499.aspx) either scalar or table-valued. The former return single values of simple types: `int`, `datetime` etc., and the latter return row sets.

There are no cursor-valued functions in SQL Server.